# Is there any way that two flutter apps can refer to same db or shared prefs?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I have two flutter apps (app A, app B) and main goal is to pull data from app A and display on app B for further processing. I have tried "unilinks" but it only launches app A instead of pulling the data and displaying on app B.

I tried "share" packages as well but do not want to display the "share" dialog explicitly.

Other way I am thinking is save the data on app A to local DB/ sharedPrefs/ file and let app B read that source. But haven't found any concrete example. (connecting to firebasedb will be worst case scenario)

Is it possible?

Comment: what platform are you targeting?

Comment: both android and iOS

Comment: sharing data between apps is specific to each platform and there doesn't seem to be an already written package in flutter for assisting with this. So if you really want to do this the just search for "Sharing data between apps iOS", "Sharing data between apps Android". However, I question if this is something you truly want to do. Usually you'll want to have a server in the middle of the 2 client apps